# How do I stop Firefox from constantly requiring me to press Enter to get into my localhost control panel which uses "HTTP basic auth"?

Tags: firefox

I use Firefox. I have a 127.0.0.1-hosted "control panel" which I've coded for myself. It is perhaps needlessly protected by a "basic HTTP auth" thingie, just to make me feel safe, even though in theory it's not supposed to allow any outside connections. Still, I need it in place to be able to feel somewhat relaxed. I can't just remove it.

Every time I load my control panel bookmark, Firefox displays a GUI box with my username and password already filled in, but doesn't automatically press Enter. I have to see that "GUI prompt" every single "session" and manually press Enter for it to continue.

This may sound like a small thing, but I'm sure a prisoner in an ancient Chinese torture chamber also didn't mind the water drops the first few hours/days... Once it has been established in my brain as something that will happen every time, I start feeling like it's a "struggle" to open my control panel, because I know it won't instantly load when I press the control panel bookmark, but instead prompt me and force me to do another input before it loads.

Is there some way to make it not behave like this? I mean, it already remembers the username/password, so it seems silly that it doesn't automatically "log in" as well. At least it should have a checkbox saying: "[ ] Do not display this prompt from now on" or something along those lines.

I can understand that it does this by default, to verify with the user that it indeed uses the "HTTP basic auth" mechanism, but they should definitely let me get rid of it when I have verified that it works as intended.

Perhaps there is an about:config for this? Please let there be one...

***Important***: If I load the bookmark several times in a row, it doesn't ask each page load. Only when I close and then open Firefox again, which inevitably happens countless times a day. ***Clearing the browser data is NOT required for it to "forget" this!***

So, to make it crystal clear: it has nothing to do with clearing browser data. I verified this myself before asking this question, just to be 100% sure. It seems to be a well-intentioned feature which backfires due to how I use my computer, and sadly, I can't change. For many reasons, I close and open Firefox (in multiple profiles) all the time.

Answer (score 2):

The instruction to auto-send the credentials for the page are set in Firefox on a `sesion` basis - i.e. when you close a browser tab it will ask again next time.

This has good reasons, and there is no setting in Firefox to override it. But you have a lot of other choices - the easiest one is to adapt your panel code, that if the IP address of the client is `127.0.0.1` it auto-logs you in. The rationale behind is, that if your server is already compromised, you don't need to think about your client credentiasl.